# How To Dark Image Background in CSS on hover?

Tags: css

How would I Darken a Image Background On Hover without use another image?

Comment: what have you tried so far ? multiple background + transition could be an hint or background-blend-mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for young browser you may use the blend-mode:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waGoEd

```css
html {
  background:url(http://lorempixel.com/300/300) rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
html:hover {
  background-blend-mode:darken;
}
```

Here a rgba() color is used, you can darken or colorish your image with any colors.

---

redish in next

```css
html {
  background:url(http://lorempixel.com/300/300) rgba(100,0,0,0.5);
}
html:hover {
  background-blend-mode:darken;
}
```

gradients can be applied too.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot darken a color on hover in pure css.
You can do something like that:

```
body {
    background-color: #efefef;
}
body:hover {
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

For darkening the color automatically you can use less for example:

```
@grey: #efefef
@grey-darker: darken(@grey, 10%);
```

and then in the style definition:

```
body {
    background-color: @grey;
    &:hover {
        background-color: @grey-darker;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is about **background images** not colors.

Answer (score -2):

use a transparent PNG image, then (with CSS) add :hover pseudo to the img tag, and define background-color as your wish.

```
img:hover {
background-color: black;
}
```